# Attached properties does not exist in namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The answers of similar questions do not help me. I am trying to use an attached property I found elsewhere. I have the following declaration in my XAML:

```
    xmlns:SAS ="clr-namespace:WPFLocalDataConnect.Tools.SelectAllSample"
```

This is used in a textbox on the view as shown:

```
        TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" SAS:TextBoxAttach.TextBoxController="{Binding}"
```

I get the following errors:

```
The property 'TextBoxAttach.TextBoxController' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:WPFLocalDataConnect.Tools'.
The name "TextBoxAttach" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WPFLocalDataConnect.Tools.SelectAllSample".
```

The name TextBoxAttached is in the SelectAllSample namespace which is stored in the Tools folder of the project WPF Local Data Connect. What is causing these errors? It looks like the file location is properly declared.

Comment: This is bug.Try remove namespace for it and give the same namespace.And from the XAML change and then recreate it.Finally rebuild your project it will correct it.I do like this

Comment: @Suren Yes it works great now, how come this bug still exists. I remember having this problem in vs2012 a little while back now using vs2015, not good enough mircosoft lol

Comment: They don't know about this bug :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, as hinted in a comment to the question.

However, `TextBoxController` must be an attached property in a class `TextBoxAttach` in namespace `WPFLocalDataConnect.Tools.SelectAllSample`:

```
namespace WPFLocalDataConnect.Tools.SelectAllSample
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextBoxControllerProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("TextBoxController", ...);

    // static getter and setter methods
}
```

The folder structure of your project is irrelevant.

Comment: This is the exact way that I had things laid out before AND after the error, I just had to retype the namespace and the class name. I already had the above. Are you sure it is not a bug? I did not change anything other than retype the exact same thing. I then rebuilt and everything worked fine. I think you may be wrong in your assertion.

Comment: I've tested it, and it works (for me). And again, it hasn't got anything to with file locations or project folders. You just have to use the correct namespace in XAML.

Comment: Thanks, but it was working for me as well, like I said, I didn't change anything the error just appeared on loading the project.